# unity screen delta to world delta

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to convert the user touch delta position to delta position of gameobject in the world, is there a util to do that?

```
   //drag
    if (duringmove && (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved))
    {
        Debug.Log("will move " + progressTrans.gameObject.name);
        endPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);

        //should convert te deltaPos here
        progressTrans.localPosition += Vector3.right * Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.x; 
        progressTrans.localPosition = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(progressTrans.localPosition.x, mostLeft, mostRight), progressTrans.localPosition.y, progressTrans.localPosition.z);


    }
```

---

Note that I'm building a 2d game using a camera with Orthographic mode

Comment: If your 2D game is "inside" a _Screen Space - Overlay_ canvas, your `Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition` value should be the same as the `localPosition` delta you want to apply. Also not sure why the `endPos = [...]` line is here ?

Comment: @Kardux thanks for the reply, the gameobject is not in a canvas, and endPos is in the purpose of maybe further usage.

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems your object will not have its `transform.position.z` changing over time, you can use something like this:

```
//drag
if (duringmove && (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved))
{
    Debug.Log("will move " + progressTrans.gameObject.name);

    Vector3 touchPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
    touchPosition.z = progressTrans.position.z;

    // World touch position
    endPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touchPosition);
    // To local position
    progressTrans.InverseTransformPoint(endPos);

    endPos.x = Mathf.Clamp(endPos.x, mostLeft, mostRight);
    endPos.y = progressTrans.localPosition.y;
    endPos.z = progressTrans.localPosition.z;

    // If you need the delta (to lerp on it, get speed, ...)
    Vector3 deltaLocalPosition = endPos - progressTrans.localPosition;

    progressTrans.localPosition = endPos;
}
```

*Hope this helps,*